# MySQL Help - Combining 2 MySQL Selects - Result in 1

Tags: mysql, select

I have two MySQL statements (see below), I would like to combine them together so if they both result in a 1 then the end result will be 1. I'm not sure how to construct this and was hoping for some help.

```
select count(*)
from monitor
where name='job_starttime' and value < ( UNIX_TIMESTAMP( ) -600)

select count(*)
from monitor
where name='job_active' and value = 0
```

So for example I would like when both statements are true to result in a value of 1, if 1 or none are true it results in a 0.

Comment: Do you want to get two rows with the count value in each row?

Comment: Just one row, so if both sql statements (not 1 sql statement) are true then result 1 shows, if not then it = 0

Comment: Why not just `(name='job_starttime' and value < ( UNIX_TIMESTAMP( ) -600)) AND (name='job_active' and value = 0)`?

Comment: @tyteen4a03 Unfortunately I tried that one and it didn't result.

Comment: Oops, misread your question.